# Do marriages in Spain or any Schengen state automatically appear in UK records?

Tags: uk, europe, uk-citizens, spouses

I am a British citizen and got married two years back in Egypt.  I moved to Spain right after my marriage, and my wife joined me in Spain on a spouse visa.  The marriage is ending soon.  Therefore, on my return back to UK:

1. Do UK officials have a record of me being married, or do I have to register my marriage first for it to be recorded?
2. If it is not recorded in the UK, can I get married in the UK again prior to my divorce from my first wife (since she left to go back to Egypt and that will take some time)?

If it is not recorded I would rather not go through divorce hassle and just carry on with my life back in UK and get married soon.

Comment: `If it is not recorded I would rather not go through divorce hassle and just carry on with my life back in UK and get married soon.` Unfortunately life does not work that way. There are laws without which the world would be more chaotic than it currently is.

Comment: Egypt is not part of Spain or Schengen by the way.

Answer (score 7):

> 1. Do UK officials have a record of me being married, or do I have to register my marriage first for it to be recorded?

They do not have a record of it until you tell them about it.

> 2. If it is not recorded in the UK, can I get married in the UK again prior to my divorce from my first wife (since she left to go back to Egypt and that will take some time)?

No.  You cannot get married in the UK while you are married to someone else.  If you do, you will be breaking at least two laws (one for falsely claiming that you are free to marry and another for bigamy).  Perhaps more importantly, your second marriage will be invalid.  This could be a problem if it comes out later that your first marriage was not dissolved at the time of your second marriage.

> I would rather not go through divorce hassle and just carry on with my life back in UK and get married soon.

Unfortunately, that will not be possible.

Comment: Or someone else tells the Home Office about the other marriage. This could happen, especially if the separation is not an amicable one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I intended to cover the possibility of someone else telling the authorities about the other marriage under "...if it comes out later...."